# VBA to save workbook - error with replacing file with same name

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the VBA Code below to automatically save a file, but allow for the user to pick the file location and name.   I have a fixed filename that I want the user to use, for example: TestImport.xlsx, but I need some code to allow them to pick the path on their specific PC.   They will be running this routine weekly, so they will likely have a previous version of the Workbook with the exact same name, so they will have to answer the dialog box prompt to replace the file.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   Cannot access 'TestImport.xlsx'

Can you help me see what the problem is with the content below?

```
Dim fd As FileDialog, fillName As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    If fd.Show = True Then
        If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
            fillName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    Else
        'Stop Code Execution for Null File String
        End
    End If

    saveFileAs = fillName

    'Cleanup
    Set fd = Nothing

    Windows("MeritImport.xlsx").Activate
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fillName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Set fd = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a fixed filename that I want the user to use, for example: TestImport.xlsx

Then let the user only select the folder location and use that to save your file. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim flname As String

    Ret = BrowseForFolder("C:\")

    If Not Ret = "" Then
        If Right(Ret, 1) <> "\" Then Ret = Ret & "\"

        flname = Ret & "TestImport.xlsx"

        MsgBox flname
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    End If
End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function
Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

When you try to use `flname` to overwrite the file (if there is already a copy) then you will get a prompt. The user can choose "Yes" or "No". If you do not want to give the user a choice then you can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

**Note**: If the copy is open then you cannot overwrite it. It will give you an error if you try to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

use

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

and then create your filename as

```
fillname = fillName & Application.PathSeparator & "TestImport.xlsx"
```

---

To stop displaying messages such as "Are you sure you want to replace this file", use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

---

To ensure that the user doesn't already have the file open in the current version of Excel (it's harder to test that it isn't open in another instance, or by another user, etc), you could use code such as:

```
'Check to ensure that TestImport.xlsx isn't currently open
On Error Resume Next
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("TestImport.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please close 'TestImport.xlsx'"
    End
End If
```

---

The final code could look like:

```
    Dim fd As FileDialog, fillName As String, wb As Workbook

    'Check to ensure that TestImport.xlsx isn't currently open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("TestImport.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please close 'TestImport.xlsx'"
        End
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fd.Title = "File Save"  ' to change the title from "Browse" to "File Save"
    If fd.Show = True Then
        If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
            fillName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End
        End If
    Else
        'Stop Code Execution for Null File String
        End
    End If
    fillName = fillName & Application.PathSeparator & "TestImport.xlsx"

    'Cleanup
    Set fd = Nothing

    Windows("MeritImport.xlsx").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fillName, _
                                      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
                                      CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Set fd = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the assistance.   I am getting an error on the following line:

Comment: @Hilly1 - your comment didn't display the line you are getting the error on

Comment: Hi YowE3K - sorry, I missed it.  I figured it out since then.  But thank you for replying.